# How to prioritize some messages using spring cloud stream with the kafka binder

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

TLDR: I would like to be able to process some urgent messages before others in the same topic.

More explanation :

I'm working on a fairly large application using many spring microservices relying on spring-cloud-stream with the kafka-binder to talk between each other for some tasks.

It can happen that a scheduled task produces lot of events. When these event are consumed intermediary events may be produced and send, and it can take quite some time till all the initial and  intermediary messages are consumed and all the work is done.

During this time, if someone wants to manually send an event of the same type, it will be queued and processed only when everything else is done.

I've been asked to see if I can not make these "manual events" be processed in priority, before all the other events.

Usually in this case you see people advocating for duplicating all the topics (`topic-normal` and `topic-urgent` for example), duplicating the `@StreamListener`. This seems a rather complicated option, because we have lots of different topics involved here. We also have some kafka-streams aggregation that would need to be rewritten to take this into account.

With a fellow developer we were thinking of maybe duplicating the consumer groups (`consumerGroupNormal`, `consumerGroupUrgentusing`) for each topic were urgent messages are needed. I would then add a priority header to each message, duplicate the `StreamListener` and consume only messages with  `priority: urgent` headers in one of the listener, and only messages with `priority:normal` in the other listener.

I would also probably create a ChannelInterceptorAdapter to add and read this "priority" header automatically ([a bit like Sleuth does it](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/blob/master/spring-cloud-sleuth-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/instrument/messaging/AbstractTraceChannelInterceptor.java)).

But I still would have to add lots of configuration for the binders to write and would need to duplicate the listeners, add the little code that checks the header and executes or not the listener code.

All in all, this looks like quite a bit of work for somehting that looks like quite a common and simple use case that could be useful for other people so I was wondering if there is not a simpler way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using two consumer groups on each topic is pretty much the only way to do it and have two listeners.

You don't however, need a custom channel interceptor; you can use the `condition` property something like `"headers['foo'].equals('urgent')"`.

Comment: Hum, I was thinking of a ChannelInterceptorAdapter to propagate automatically the header when producing subsequent messages (to automatically keep the urgency). This is what Sleuth does with the SpanId header. As developpers we do not have to care about the traceid, sleuth injects and reads it automatically wherever needed.

Comment: I didn't think of the condition property though, this simplifies the `StreamListener` further, thanks !

Comment: Do you think it's worth creating an issue on the spring cloud stream's github to ask for such a feature ?

Comment: It won't hurt, but I don't know how much traction it will get. Most people would simply use a separate priority topic. IMO, it's a waste of CPU and network bandwidth to have two consumers on the same topic with one discarding most of the messages.